# C# error: Unable to load DLL 'AutoItX3.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, dll, autoit-c#-wrapper

DLL is available inside '**References**'.

I can able to run the test using '*Test Explorer*' successfully

**Problem:**
Same test when im running from mstest commands- im getting the following error,

```
error: Unable to load DLL 'AutoItX3.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Where i'm wrong ? can anyone show me the way for resolving this issue!
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be late, but if you still need an answer, here is my way: Change platform target of your project.

In visual studio, right click project -> Properties -> Build > Platform target -> Try to change x86 or x64.

platform target

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Do one thing

register your AutoItX3.dll:
Bu opening the CMD in Administration and execute the below command, change the path of according to your location

regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\AutoItX\AutoItX3.dll"

you will get a message box telling you it was successful.

Now try to run the test